# Where does ReSharper store the "Namespace Provider" settings?

Tags: resharper

If I go to Solution Explorer and highlight a folder, ReSharper adds a property to the Properties window called "Namespace Provider".

**When I change the "Namespace Provider" property, where does ReSharper store it?**

I've changed this property to False for one of the folders in our project, and I want to check the change into version control. But my *SolutionName*.6.0.ReSharper file didn't change, even after I exited and restarted Visual Studio. I also opened the .ReSharper.user file in a text editor and snooped around, but it doesn't look like this property is stored there either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of ReSharper 8 it is stored in a `ProjectName.csproj.DotSettings` file with the following format:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary>
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/NamespaceProvider/NamespaceFoldersToSkip/=**FolderToSkip**/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is saved in a project-level ReSharper properties file: **ProjectName.csproj.ReSharper**

There's a section that goes like this:

```
<NamespaceFolders>
    <SkipFolder>2362DD64-84CF-4ED0-B4F7-94577E33A1DC/d:Content</SkipFolder>
  </NamespaceFolders>
```

Comment: Ah! I was looking in the solution's .ReSharper file -- didn't realize there was one for the project too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I set it to `false` for me on the "Properties" folder (containing `AssemblyInfo.cs`) in one of my projects (VS2010, Resharper 5.1).

It creates a files in the project directory called `<ProjectName>.csproj.ReSharper`.

The contents of the file were this:

```
<Configuration>
  <NamespaceFolders>
    <SkipFolder>83F5FDE9-BC4A-45E6-A7CA-E2EF85388AE5/d:Properties</SkipFolder>
  </NamespaceFolders>
</Configuration>
```